# Break after braces in initializer

Tags: c++, struct, clang-format

I am looking on how to make clang-format allowing this format:

```
std::vector<MyStruct> data = 
{
  {
    0,
    true
  },
  {
    1,
    false
  }
}
```

Comment: This is just wrong. It looks like a function or class. Put the brackets after the = sign

Comment: what is the reason you want to do this?

Comment: @PetarVelev - Let's not turn this into a religious war, shall we?

Comment: I agree with you @PetarVelev, but this style is expected in my new job...

Comment: Why do you have to use structs inside vectors, why not use classes instead...???